# Why am I getting data undefined when I can see the data?

Tags: react-native, es6-promise

I have been staring at these action creators:

```
import * as types from './constants';
import * as endpoints from 'endpoints';
import * as requester from 'services/Requester';
import * as helpers from 'account-settings/helpers/data-helpers';

export function fetchPrefences({Key}) {
  return dispatch => {
    const url = `${endpoints.v2.INDIVIDUALS}/${Key}/preferences`;
    requester.sendGet(url).then(data => {
      const payload = helpers.sortPreferences(data);
      dispatch({
        type: types.SET_USER_PREFERENCES,
        payload,
      });
    });
  };
}

export function fetchTopics() {
  return dispatch => {
    requester.sendGet(endpoints.TOPICS_OF_CONCERN).then(data => {
      dispatch({
        type: types.SET_USER_TOPICS,
        payload: data.Items,
      });
    });
  };
}

export function handleStateChange(payload) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_NEW_PREFERENCES,
    payload,
  };
}

export function handleUpdateTopics({topics, involved}, updateBoth = false) {
  return dispatch => {
    return requester
      .sendPut(endpoints.TOPICS_OF_CONCERN, {
        Items: topics,
      })
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.SET_USER_TOPICS,
          payload: data.Items,
        });
        if (updateBoth) {
          dispatch(handleUpdatePreferences({involved}));
        }
      });
  };
}

export function handleUpdateGetInvoved({involved}) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {auth} = getState();
    //prettier-ignore
    const url = `${endpoints.v2.INDIVIDUALS}/${auth.user.Key}/preferences`;
    return requester
      .sendPut(url, {
        Items: involved,
      })
      .then(data => {
        const payload = helpers.sortPreferences(data);
        dispatch({
          type: types.SET_USER_PREFERENCES,
          payload,
        });
      });
  };
}
```

And it's clear I am getting `data` as undefined with this message:

[image]

What is not clear is why? When I do a `curl`, the data is there:

> {"items":[{"category":"None","key":"2883040c-88b8-4899-bd47-114a560d085b","displayText":"Energy
> Costs","isSelected":false,"order":1},{"category":"None","key":"a745a3d6-0f64-4595-8734-6082d9c914f7","displayText":"Regulations","isSelected":false,"order":7},{"category":"None","key":"51797a61-8016-4817-a46e-72dee3d8239a","displayText":"Minimum
> Wage","isSelected":false,"order":5},{"category":"None","key":"381e24d0-2668-4a69-a993-7d5e1ecaec3b","displayText":"Taxes","isSelected":false,"order":8},{"category":"None","key":"dfaf22cb-111a-46f3-bce3-93fbf4a91490","displayText":"Unemployment
> Insurance","isSelected":false,"order":9},{"category":"None","key":"c55b5d2a-a0f3-4c35-bf59-b433259b2059","displayText":"Workers
> Compensation","isSelected":false,"order":10},{"category":"None","key":"d4b787d4-550b-4866-a5cc-c6a2de61a91a","displayText":"Healthcare","isSelected":false,"order":4},{"category":"None","key":"c2557854-421d-4b2f-810f-caadf938cded","displayText":"Government
> Spending","isSelected":false,"order":3},{"category":"None","key":"cf91f638-c5fa-4252-be01-dce504ae369d","displayText":"Private
> Property
> Rights","isSelected":false,"order":6},{"category":"None","key":"0eae5ccf-2ba5-41bd-9111-efe7acafa512","displayText":"Finding
> Qualified Employees","isSelected":false,"order":2}]}%

In Swagger, I check, the data is there:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "2883040c-88b8-4899-bd47-114a560d085b",
      "displayText": "Energy Costs",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "a745a3d6-0f64-4595-8734-6082d9c914f7",
      "displayText": "Regulations",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 7
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "51797a61-8016-4817-a46e-72dee3d8239a",
      "displayText": "Minimum Wage",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 5
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "381e24d0-2668-4a69-a993-7d5e1ecaec3b",
      "displayText": "Taxes",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 8
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "dfaf22cb-111a-46f3-bce3-93fbf4a91490",
      "displayText": "Unemployment Insurance",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 9
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "c55b5d2a-a0f3-4c35-bf59-b433259b2059",
      "displayText": "Workers Compensation",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 10
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "d4b787d4-550b-4866-a5cc-c6a2de61a91a",
      "displayText": "Healthcare",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 4
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "c2557854-421d-4b2f-810f-caadf938cded",
      "displayText": "Government Spending",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "cf91f638-c5fa-4252-be01-dce504ae369d",
      "displayText": "Private Property Rights",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 6
    },
    {
      "category": "None",
      "key": "0eae5ccf-2ba5-41bd-9111-efe7acafa512",
      "displayText": "Finding Qualified Employees",
      "isSelected": false,
      "order": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I noticed that in the code the items property was written as `Items`, I tried to change it to `items` to match the data property, that did nothing.

A colleague suggested the issue could be in the `requester` object, I do have a question about it too:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import LocalStorage from './LocalStorage';
import env from 'env';
import * as appcenter from 'utils/appcenterLogger';
import * as titlesHelper from 'utils/titleCaser';

let expired = false;

export const instance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    NFIBAppID: env.NFIBAppID,
  },
});

let preHeaders = {};
async function mergeConfig(config) {
  try {
    const access = await LocalStorage.get('access');
    preHeaders = access;
    return {...config, headers: {...access}};
  } catch (error) {
    return {...config};
  }
}

export async function sendGet(url, config = {}) {
  if (expired) {
    return;
  }

  const now = new Date();

  return instance
    .get(url, await mergeConfig(config))
    .then(response => {
      return saveHeaders(response, now, url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return catchErros(error, now, url);
    });
}

export async function sendPost(url, data, config = {}) {
  if (expired) {
    return;
  }

  const now = new Date();
  return instance
    .post(url, titlesHelper.lowerCaser(data), await mergeConfig(config))
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return saveHeaders(response, now, url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return catchErros(error, now, url);
    });
}
export async function sendPut(url, data, config = {}) {
  if (expired) {
    return;
  }

  const now = new Date();
  return instance
    .put(url, titlesHelper.lowerCaser(data), await mergeConfig(config))
    .then(response => {
      return saveHeaders(response, now, url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return catchErros(error, now, url);
    });
}
export async function sendPatch(url, data, config = {}) {
  if (expired) {
    return;
  }

  const now = new Date();
  return instance
    .patch(url, data, await mergeConfig(config))
    .then(response => {
      return saveHeaders(response, now, url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return catchErros(error, now, url);
    });
}
export async function sendDelete(url, data, config = {}) {
  if (expired) {
    return;
  }

  const now = new Date();
  return instance
    .delete(url, await mergeConfig(config))
    .then(response => {
      return saveHeaders(response, now, url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return catchErros(error, now, url);
    });
}

export function saveHeaders({data, headers}, timeSent, url) {
  try {
    if (headers && headers.authorizationtoken) {
      LocalStorage.save('access', {
        AuthorizationToken: headers.authorizationtoken,
      });
    }
    const timeReceived = new Date();
    LocalStorage.save('lastTimeRequestSent', timeReceived);
    appcenter.trackRequestTiming(timeSent, timeReceived, headers, url, false);
    return titlesHelper.toTitleCase(data);
  } catch (_e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function catchErros({error, timeSent}, url) {
  try {
    const timeReceived = new Date();
    LocalStorage.save('lastTimeRequestSent', timeReceived);
    appcenter.trackRequestTiming(timeSent, timeReceived, error, url, true);

    if (error && error.response) {
      saveHeaders({
        headers: preHeaders,
      });

      const {data} = error.response;
      const message = data.message || data.Message;
      if (message.includes('TokenExpired')) {
        expired = true;
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(titlesHelper.toTitleCase(error.response.data));
  } catch (_e) {
    return error;
  }
}

export function resetTokenExpired() {
  expired = false;
}
```

I am seeing Promise syntax being mixed with async/await syntax, could this be causing an issue?

I tried to see if perhaps the issue was with the authorization token, so I console logged it:

```
let preHeaders = {};
async function mergeConfig(config) {
  try {
    const access = await LocalStorage.get('access');
    console.log(access);
    preHeaders = access;
    return {...config, headers: {...access}};
  } catch (error) {
    return {...config};
  }
}
```

but I am successfully getting that back:

```
{AuthorizationToken: "<bunch-o-numbers>"}
```

What I know at this point is that without the logic inside of the `saveHeaders()` function, a registered users' password will return undefined.

To complicate things, this application uses action helpers, which I have never implemented, but I see that `Items` property in there all over the place, keep in mind that the original warning read `Items`, but I changed it everywhere to `items` to make it match the JSON `item` property in the hope that would be the fix.

However, I have now come across these action helper files with the following code, `action-helpers.js`:

```
import * as endpoints from 'endpoints';
import * as requester from 'services/Requester';
import compareDesc from 'date-fns/compare_desc';

export async function fetchTransaction() {
  try {
    const response = await requester.sendGet(endpoints.TRANSACTIONS);
    const {Items = []} = response;
    return Items.sort((a, b) => compareDesc(a.DateTime, b.DateTime));
  } catch (error) {
    return [];
  }
}
```

and in `data-helpers.js`:

```
export function sortPreferences(data) {
  const sorted = data.Items.sort((a, b) => a.Order - b.Order);
  const communications = sorted.filter(
    p => p.Category === 'CommunicationPreferences'
  );
  const privacy = sorted.filter(p => p.Category === 'MemberPrivacy');
  const involved = sorted.filter(p => p.Category === 'GetInvolved');

  const format = data.EmailFormatType === 'HTML' ? 'HTML' : 'Plain Text';
  return {
    communications,
    privacy,
    involved,
    emailFormatType: format,
    isEmailAllowed: data.IsEmailAllowed,
    isPhoneAllowed: data.IsPhoneAllowed,
  };
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you check the 'requester' object, it is most likely you are not resolving the promise correctly

Comment: @MazinoSUkah, the `requester` object is just pulling in and saving the authorization token and doing it successfully, I did check that.

Comment: hmmm can you show a snippet of what the requester object looks like ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah, I pasted in the OP above.

Comment: i am not sure what this line does ```titlesHelper.toTitleCase(data);``` but returning just ```data``` should work

Comment: @MazinoSUkah, it didn't break anything, but it did not resolve that error.

Comment: @MazinoSUkah, please take another look I have updated my post.

Comment: Its really hard to spot where the problem is coming from, it will be nice if you can reproduce the issue on jfiddle. By doing so, you will most likely figure out the issue, but we are still here to assist. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not getting the expected response from your `requester` function.

Try logging the response from the `requester` and see the output. You might have to use `response.json()` to resolve the promise correctly. This is assuming your `requester` class/function works like that.

Comment: Nishant, the `requester` object is just pulling in and saving the authorization token to access the data to the device and I did check that and its doing it successfully. I pasted it in the OP

Comment: 1. You can mix match Promises and async/await, no issues there.  2. Do check each of your inner functions like `saveHeaders` and it's return value. I don't think it's returning the expected response object. `titleHelpers.toTitleCase` function is returning what?

Comment: 3. Also check `sendX` method, are returning errors instead of throwing them. They should throw errors so that in you `fetchTopics` method you can use `catch` block and handle those errors.

Comment: Did changing `Items` key to `items` in `data-helper.js` do any good?

Comment: I thought it would work because I saw this line of code `const {Items = []} = response;`, but I don't know where its pulling `Items` from, because there is no `Items` property inside the JSON returned, there is only an `items` property which is an array of objects. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `Items` to `items` in all the files and try. Also add console.logs to every function's return value so that you can check which value goes where.

Comment: I did try changing `Items` to `items` already and that did not help. I think this may be part of a larger issue I am finding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266777/react-native-why-isnt-my-child-component-receiving-props?noredirect=1#comment99150171_56266777

Comment: I know this is too late, but I noticed just now the warning says, you are trying to access property `items` of an `undefined` object. This means your response object is `undefined`, in `fetchTransactions` function I guess.